# Tag cloud: keywords and content

Tags: web, terminology, tag-cloud

From the [Wikipedia article *Tag cloud*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud#History):

> used primarily to visualize the frequency distribution of keyword metadata that describe website content

Ok, but: Frequency distribution of keyword of the current page into the content OR is the frequency distribution of keyword metadata into the entire website content?

Answer (score 0):

A **tag cloud** (hyperlinked) typically shows the tags of the whole website, and clicking on a tag leads to a page listing all the documents tagged with this tag. Having such a linked tag cloud for a single document wouldn’t really make sense, as there would be no useful link target (Where should the link lead to? To the first occurence of the keyword in the document? Not really useful.)

This is also what the part you quote says: for a *website* ("that describe website content"), not a *webpage*.

A **text/word cloud** (not hyperlinked) typically shows the words of the current document.